# Definition of the refractive index

Tags: optics, conventions, definition, refraction

My textbook says the absolute refractive index of a medium  $$n = \dfrac{c}{v}$$

where $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum and $v$ is the speed of light in the medium.

Why hasn't it been chosen the other way round i.e. $n = \dfrac{v}{c}$?

Comment: Wikipedia has some relevant historical info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#History & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law#History Presumably, writing the refractive index ratio as a fraction >1 goes back 1000 years or more, but Wikipedia isn't clear on that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a definition - but using $c/v$ rather than $v/c$ it means that objects with a larger refractive index bend light more, which seems the right way round. It is more natural to work with bending angles (lenses, telescopes, spectacles) rather than the actual velocity which is not usually something you perceive directly (unless you're using fibre optics over long distances and worried about signal timing).

Answer (score 2):

As it's just a definition, I'm not sure there's any fundamental reason for the choice other than it gives a higher number the more light slows down in a medium and thus the more light is refracted at an interface. One might ask, for instance, why the coefficient of friction was chosen as F/N instead of N/F. Again, larger coefficients mean more friction. So it appears these definitions are useful.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the definition of the refractive index. Its definition is $n^2 = \epsilon_r$. The relative dielectric "constant" is in turn defined as $\epsilon_r = 1+ \chi_e$ where the polarisation $P = \epsilon_0 \chi_e E$ is related to the applied field by the electric susceptibility. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility.

In the above I have assumed an isotropic medium, at rest, with linear response and relative magnetic permeability $\mu=1$.
This includes metals. Within these limitations the treatment is generally valid. In the most general case the dielectric "constant" is a rank 2 lLorentz tensor where the elements depend on the frequency and on the direction of $\vec k$.

To answer your question, there is no fundamental argument against setting $n=1/\sqrt{\epsilon_r}$. It is the conventional definition, again with the limitations given.

Comment: Why do you say it's this rather than $c/v$, which is the only definition I've ever seen and is the one in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Definition ?  $P = \epsilon_0 \chi_e E$ is only applicable to a subset of materials/media.